# How is this data encoded?

Tags: encoding

I've found several website exchange data with the browser through a seemingly similar encoding consisting of `[A-z0-9/+]` such as

`11UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YWJdm48m5cJDWuLLIYaigN6cCfiKOtB/Xb00yCTJRLU1iZilyDQAF8okuqrX2gHm2pVsKeYHWxDNNLB9teqqv2msRNJADEmHqHJWhIpgq6kB4LRtzrU7x1ms9VfChurilER4JfNiBiNqsetbxxPaDn3+SZFhbqDh1V6ufUeNbri49YKKra3WOe4=`

or

`11UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YWJdm48m5cJDWuLLIYaigN6cCfiKOtB/Xb00yCTJRLU1iZilyDQAF8okuqrX2gHm2pVsKeYHWxDN9IdK3oj1qFvfsjLKRaHSu60i6RSRagBfu5CtrYWAiHIZXA5wKwOGZwh5lUwHApYhPZzbdpfT6ubbVr5WFlrO5VHDBw9bFi1hduxQaia2i8k=`

or

`11UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YUbM7JQKVn66Jan93YWDhnDQ1nd8g669ScUfvmjw724qB521xitv+brNAzNRj46wgJBqF3rIKqgVRRsk8d9ccybqIhLm0E76CUjS/XnuWXzxZM+wTAx8lSbkiqHWg7hcwb7Fr8bMqW0d+1gZqUJto3zdImOPwDTNRFmEmRhWnOEAV86C5yFfCyw=`

It appears to be more than a simple ID - rather encoded data of some sort.

I've tried Base 64 - the second half (following the /) appears to be a valid base64 encoding of non Text data.

The hex values of the example strings (base64 decoded after the /) are:

> 5d bd 34 c8 24 c9 44 b5 35 89 98 a5 c8 34 00 17 ca 24 ba aa d7 da 01 e6 da 95 6c 29 e6 07 5b 10 cd 34 b0 7d b5 ea aa bf 69 ac 44 d2 40 0c 49 87 a8 72 56 84 8a 60 ab a9 01 e0 b4 6d ce b5 3b c7 59 ac f5 57 c2 86 ea e2 94 44 78 25 f3 62 06 23 6a b1 eb 5b c7 13 da 0e 7d fe 49 91 61 6e a0 e1 d5 5e ae 7d 47 8d 6e b8 b8 f5 82 8a ad ad d6 39 ee
>
> 5d bd 34 c8 24 c9 44 b5 35 89 98 a5 c8 34 00 17 ca 24 ba aa d7 da 01 e6 da 95 6c 29 e6 07 5b 10 cd f4 87 4a de 88 f5 a8 5b df b2 32 ca 45 a1 d2 bb ad 22 e9 14 91 6a 00 5f bb 90 ad ad 85 80 88 72 19 5c 0e 70 2b 03 86 67 08 79 95 4c 07 02 96 21 3d 9c db 76 97 d3 ea e6 db 56 be 56 16 5a ce e5 51 c3 07 0f 5b 16 2d 61 76 ec 50 6a 26 b6 8b c9
>
> 5e 7b 96 5f 3c 59 33 ec 13 03 1f 25 49 b9 22 a8 75 a0 ee 17 30 6f b1 6b f1 b3 2a 5b 47 7e d6 06 6a 50 9b 68 df 37 48 98 e3 f0 0d 33 51 16 61 26 46 15 a7 38 40 15 f3 a0 b9 c8 57 c2 cb

Comment: knowing the `decoded` string could be of much help...

Comment: Base 64 encoding would be a good start. Whether it's encoded beyond that will depend a lot.

Comment: I realise it's a bit ambiguous. I've only ever seen the encoded version thus do not have a decoded version available.

I've tried base64 - it was my first idea as well, however i did not get any plausable results.

I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Edit: it appears the second half following the / is a valid base64 encoding of binary data.